# OAuth2 How to determine if redirect uri uses tls?

Tags: php, ssl, https, oauth-2.0, tls1.2

I am developing an Oauth 2 authentication server and I have a problem with endpoint redirection.

Here is what the RFC says that I try to follow scrupulously:

> 3.1.2.1.  Endpoint Request Confidentiality
>
> The redirection endpoint SHOULD require the use of TLS as described
> in Section 1.6 when the requested response type is "code" or "token",
> or when the redirection request will result in the transmission of
> sensitive credentials over an open network.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2.1

**Here is my question:**

I know if the current request uses HTTPS with the $_SERVER ['HTTPS'] superglobal, but ***how do I determine if the url I'm going to redirect is using TLS
?***

```
header("Location: $redirectUri");
```

Do I only rely on the protocol (https: // at the beginning of the URL)? On headers returned by a CURL request made before redirection (check the presence of the Strict-Transport-Security header) ? If not how should I do it?

---

*PS: Normally it is not necessary but in case. Here is the complete code:
https://github.com/alexandre-le-borgne/oauth-server/blob/master/src/OAuth2/Endpoints/AuthorizationEndpoint.php#L185*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is that it is enough to check the presence of the https at the beginning of the URL.